# Maximo web service Sync Response: what is the purpose of messageid?

Tags: soapui, maximo

Maximo supports integration via web services. When I hit one of my Maximo web services with soapUI, it comes back with a `messageID` attribute in the `<Sync..>` tag, as shown in this image:

[image: messageID]

What is the purpose of this `messageID`?

Comment: It looks like you need to read [ask] and [example]. Just a link to a picture doesn't count as a question.

Comment: Pardon, as I am new here. Ill do that. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

messageID is a

> Unique identifier generated for all messages

Page 345, http://web.archive.org/web/20191010153949/https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLKT6_7.6.0.5/com.ibm.mif.doc/pdf_mif.pdf?view=kc

[image]